# Running process in parallel for data collection

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, serial-port

I am collecting data from two pieces of equipment using serial ports (scale and conductivity probe). I need to continuously collect data from the scale which I average between collection points of the conductivity probe (roughly a minuet).

Thus I need to run two processes at the same time. One that collects data from the scale, and other which waits for data from the conductivity probe, once it gets the data it would send a command to the other process in order to get the collected scale data, which is then time stamped and saved into .csv file.

I looked into subprocess but it I cant figure out how to reset a running script. Any suggestions on what to look into.

Comment: I am useing python. I will look onto threads for python then. Thanks

Comment: how does _how to reset a running script_ relate to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using threads you could also implementing your data sources as generators and just loop over them to consume the incoming data and do something with it. Perhaps using two different generators and zipping them together, actually would be a nice experiment I'm not entirely sure it can be done...